# How to use :not() pseudo-class to exclude a child element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Let's say that I have an h1 tag that looks like this:

```html
<h1>
  I don't want to see this, <span>but I want to see this.</span>
</h1>
```

What I need is by using just CSS to make the `<h1>` invisible without affecting the `<span>`.  This is what it should look like:

```
but I want to see this.
```

Even though this works fine:

```css
h1 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
span {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

It might be better to use just one selector, I was thinking that by using the `:not()` pseudo-class I could easily solve this problem. Something like this:

```css
h1:not(span) {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

This doesn't work though and I can't understand why. Any ideas why this is happening?

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akimo/y3edg5rc/)

Comment: This only works for the same level, you need at least 2 spans then you could do something like this: `h1 > span:not(:last-child) { visibility: hidden }`

Comment: I would concentrate more on making things work than worrying on how many selectors it takes. Speaking as someone who reviews code a lot, I'd rather see code that I can understand immediately than code that's shorter, but harder to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, in the end,  I'm just trying to be a better coder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This doesn't work though and I can't understand why. Any ideas why this is happening?

Because the `h1` is never a `span`. This means the negation argument is always true and the rule is always in effect.

This is the code:

```css
h1:not(span) {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

The logic here goes like this: *Target all h1s that are not spans*. That's always true, so `visibility: hidden` is always active. It's the same as using just `h1`.

The logic you seek is: *Ignore spans that are children of h1s*. Totally different.

I think using two selectors, like you already have, is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me understand this, that means there's not a straight "ignore child of a tag selector"?

Comment: That's not necessarily true. It depends on many things, such as the structure of your HTML, the CSS properties you're using (inheritance is an issue), and the overall goal.

Answer (score 0):

The `visibility` property isn't being applied to `h1's` children, it's being applied directly to `h1`. You can't target `h1` and it's children in a single selector.

Comment: Thanks for the disambiguation.